# make the div content autoscrolling right to left with a nice animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I make a div content (any type of content: table, image, text,etc.) autoscrolling from right to left with an elegant animation?

Thank you very much,
regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try the scrollTo plugin?

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

**Update:**
It seems you want something like this: (check the last example)
http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/serialScroll/

Comment: interesting, but can't no circular mode :(

Answer (score 0):

Like this, maybe? http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/

> jCarousel is a jQuery plugin for controlling a list of items in horizontal or vertical order. The items, which can be static HTML content or loaded with (or without) AJAX, can be scrolled back and forth (with or without animation).

Comment: I think I found what I was looking for: jQuery Cycle.
Really easy to use and well documented.
Thanks again.